# Merge two rows in columns based on condition

Tags: r, replace, merge

I am new here, as well as to R, and I couldn't find any past queries that answered my following question, so I apologise if this has already been brought up before.

I am trying to merge the ID columns from two different datasets into one, but some of the IDs in the rows have been coded differently. I need to replace all the "LNZ_" IDs with the "LNZ.", however, I cannot figure out how I would go about doing this.

```
df_1 <- data.frame(ID_1 = c("LNZ_00001", "LNZ_00002", "LNZ_00003", "DFG00001", "CWD00001"),
                   Sex=c("M","F","F","M","F"))

df_2 <- data.frame(ID_2 = c("LNZ.00001", "LNZ.00002", "LNZ_00003", "DFG00001", "CWD00001"),
                   Type=c("S","S","B","B","B"), 
                   AGE=c(56,75,66,64,64))
```

The above is similar to the datasets that I have, only more scaled down. I hope this is somewhat clear, and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `df_1$ID_1 <- sub("LNZ_", "LNZ.", df_1$ID_1)`, which has nothing to do with `merge`, but after that then merge(df_1, df_2, by.x="ID_1", by.y="ID_2", all=TRUE)` works without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with merging is that your `ID` columns have different formatting for some of the entries which are supposed to be matched. Therefore you need to modify those values to match before performing the merge. In the examples you gave, the difference is between a period separator (`.`) and an underscore (`_`). If your real data has more complex issues, you may need to use different code to clean up those values.

However, once that is resolved, you can perform your merge easily. Here I've used the {tidyverse} packages to accomplish both steps in one pipe chain.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- data.frame(ID_1 = c("LNZ_00001", "LNZ_00002", "LNZ_00003", "DFG00001", "CWD00001"), Sex=c("M","F","F","M","F"))

df_2 <- data.frame(ID_2 = c("LNZ.00001", "LNZ.00002", "LNZ_00003", "DFG00001", "CWD00001"), Type=c("S","S","B","B","B"), AGE=c(56,75,66,64,64))

df_2 %>% 
  mutate(ID_2 = str_replace(ID_2, "\\.", "\\_")) %>% 
  left_join(df_1, by = c("ID_2" = "ID_1"))
#>        ID_2 Type AGE Sex
#> 1 LNZ_00001    S  56   M
#> 2 LNZ_00002    S  75   F
#> 3 LNZ_00003    B  66   F
#> 4  DFG00001    B  64   M
#> 5  CWD00001    B  64   F
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer so the community will know it's closed and others can benefit from it.

Comment: FYI @DanAdams, the topic of politely reminding new users to accept questions has been discussed many times on meta, and over the last year or so the mindset has changed a little. The [current stance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/584676), and while I refute the effectiveness of their "improved new features", it is likely that your comment here may be removed (flagged as not relevant). I caution against doing this repeatedly, as it might lead towards a nasty-gram email asking you to desist. Just a friendly note.

Comment: @DanAdams, Thanks for the reminder, I was trying to figure out how to do that, but I got there in the end :)

Comment: @r2evans - thanks for that note. It always feels like an uncomfortable blend of self-serving community maintenance. Will avoid in future.

Comment: I often lean more towards community maintenance, but the moderators either disagree or have their hands tied. Either way, I feel their assumptions are incorrect yet maintenance and polite reminders are suppressed. Having said that, many users _clearly_ are fishing for having their answer accepted, so I also believe wholeheartedly that requesting "accept" needed to be done with care. Either way, they haven't asked my opinion :-)